# Error al ejecutar una consulta en SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me sale un error al ejecutar mi consulta, me podrían decir a que se debe?, gracias.

Comment: Hola
Indícanos la intercalación del SQL Server y el de tu base de datos, primero. Segundo, revisa el script de creación de tu esquema de base de datos.
Esto se debe a que son diferentes y es necesario un COLLATE en tu script

Comment: supongo que debe ser por el idioma, tengo el SQL Server 2017 y el SSMS 2018, como hago con el COLLATE? @EdgarVazquez

Comment: Prueba con esto aplicado a tus campos y me dices
SELECT Campo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS FROM Tabla

Comment: este es mi query:

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon tu consulta ahi.
Saludos